# Does discarding a task with the discard keyword cause any side-effects?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

As of C# 7 we can use the discard `_` to discard unused variables. One of the things I use this for is in fire-and-forget tasks.

Consider this method:

```
public Task Example()
{
    // Do some fire-and-forget stuff.
}
```

You can fire-and-forget this task by simply not awaiting the task: `Example()`, however this still gives you a warning. With the discard keyword we are now able to use: `_ = Example()`, which gets rid of this warning. I'm wondering if this has any nasty side-effects that I should be aware of? (Other than what MSDN states: "This has the effect of suppressing the exception that the operation throws as it is about to complete.")

Comment: That is exactly what the discard syntax is introduced for.

Comment: @Sweeper Got an internal comment about using the discard like this will garbage collect the task. But since it is fire-and-forget, surely this is okay?

Comment: Well, it depends on the context too. If this was in a command line app, for example, the task wouldn't complete.

Comment: @DavidG Wouldn't the same problem occur without the `_ =`? Since the command line app would just shut without awaiting.

Comment: @Timmeh I am not that well-informed about the way GC works with Tasks, but I'm pretty sure `_ = Example()` compiles to the same IL as `Example()`. If the latter works, the former should do too.

Comment: @Sweeper I was thinking the same, I'll check the IL to be sure ^^

Comment: @Sweeper Yep, identical IL. I guess "No" is a valid answer to my question to, so feel free to add an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards#a-standalone-discard) specifically has a `Task` example

Comment: @phuzi The documentation having an example for something doesn't guarantee there is no side-effects. I came here because I couldn't find anything conclusive in the documentation, sadly.

Comment: `_ =` might impact GC **depending** on what your alternative would be. If you store the task into a named variable instead, and force that variable to not go out of scope, then `_ =` might cause the task object to be eligible for collection earlier than with the variable. However, this will not prevent the task execution to complete, so it should not matter in the slightest. Compared to omitting `_ =` and simply calling the method, it will not make a difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The discard syntax is simply a syntactic sugar to suppress the warning of "the return value of this expression is unused". These two lines compile to the same IL:

```
_ = Example();
Example();
```

They both become the same `call` instruction.

Therefore, if `Example()` works for you, so will `_ = Example()`.